Orthogonal functions of spherical orbital angular momentum operator
In the context of quantum mechanics everybody knows the angular momentum operator ($\theta$, $\phi$ spherical coordinates):
$$ \boldsymbol{L}^2 = - \left[ \frac{1}{\sin \theta} \partial_{\theta} ( \sin \theta \partial_{\theta}) + \frac{1}{\sin^2 \theta} \partial^2_{\phi} \right] $$
and the associated spherical harmonics which are its eigenfunctions:
$$ \boldsymbol{L}^2 Y_l^m(\theta,\phi) = l(l+1) Y_l^m(\theta,\phi) $$
These functions form an orthonormal set such as:
$$ \langle Y_{l'}^{m'} \vert Y_l^m \rangle = \int_0^{2 \pi} d \phi \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin \theta d \theta Y_{l'}^{m' *} Y_l^m = \delta_{l,l'} \delta_{m,m'}$$
So obviously we have:
$$ \langle Y_{l}^{m} \vert \boldsymbol{L}^2 Y_l^m \rangle = l(l+1) $$
Question:
Do they exists a set of functions $\Psi_i \neq Y_0^0$ such as (I need at least 2 different from zero and normalized such as $\langle \Psi_i \vert \Psi_i \rangle = 1$):
$$ \langle \Psi_i \vert \boldsymbol{L}^2 \Psi_i \rangle = 0$$
?
So instead to be eigenfunction of the operator $\boldsymbol{L}^2$ "they rotate" under the action of $\boldsymbol{L}^2$ and become orthogonal to himself. I don't know if this kind of functions exist, it is like the opposite of an eigenfunction.
Thanks for reading.

$L^2$ is positive-definite because all its eigenvalues are positive, hence $\langle\psi|L^2|\psi\rangle \ge 0$ with an equality when $\psi \propto Y_0^0$ only.

Consider such a function $\psi$. Since spherical harmonics form a complete orthonormal basis of the function space $\mathcal{L}^2(S^2\to\mathbb{C})$, we can write $\psi$ as $\psi = \sum_{\ell,m} \langle Y_\ell^m | \psi \rangle~|Y_\ell^m \rangle$. We then have
$$
\begin{aligned}
L^2\psi &= L^2\left(\sum_{\ell,m} \langle Y_\ell^m | \psi \rangle~|Y_\ell^m \rangle\right) = \sum_{\ell,m} \langle Y_\ell^m | \psi \rangle~|L^2Y_\ell^m \rangle = \sum_{\ell,m} \ell(\ell+1)\langle Y_\ell^m | \psi \rangle~|Y_\ell^m \rangle \\
\implies 0&=\langle \psi | L^2 \psi\rangle = \left\langle\left.\sum_{\ell,m} \langle Y_\ell^m | \psi \rangle~\langle Y_\ell^m |\right|\sum_{\ell,m} \ell(\ell+1)\langle Y_\ell^m | \psi \rangle~|Y_\ell^m \rangle\right\rangle \\
&= \sum_{\ell,m}\ell(\ell+1)|\langle Y_\ell^m | \psi \rangle|^2.
\end{aligned}
$$
In the last step, we have used the orthonormality of $Y_\ell^m$ to cancel all cross terms and simplify with $\langle Y_\ell^m|Y_\ell^m\rangle=1$. My apologies if there are any problems with the bra-ket notation. Now notice the following. Each term of this sum is non-negative, so in order for the sum to be zero, each term must be zero. This presents us with two cases:

$\ell=0$: In this case, $\langle Y_0^0 | \psi\rangle$ can take on any value and the term is still zero.

$\ell >0$: In these cases, in order for $\ell(\ell+1)|\langle Y_\ell^m | \psi\rangle|^2$ to be zero, we must have $|\langle Y_\ell^m | \psi\rangle|^2=0$, which implies $\langle Y_\ell^m | \psi\rangle=0$.


Removing all of the zero terms from the sum, the sum reads $\psi = \langle Y_0^0 | \psi\rangle~|Y_0^0\rangle$. Therefore, any such function $\psi$ must be a multiple of $Y_0^0$.

Arf, yeah I see if I want my square integrable function, then that should be a sum of spherical harmonics, it is unfortunate for me. Thanks dude

The main issue is that the angular momentum operator only real and non-negative eigenvalues. I believe that is sufficient to show that the objects you seek can’t exist
